# C++ : Working of sine function

Tags: c++

I am trying to plot a sine curve in C++ and came across something interesting.

I have a function that returns sine value of a value in degree

```
double sind(double a)
{
    return sin(a*3.14159/180);
}
```

Now in the main function

```
sind(18)==sind(18)?cout<<1:cout<<0;
```

I write the above code. The result seems to be false and it prints 0 on the console.
But according to me sin(18) and sin(18) are equal. So what is happening in the computer's mind?

Also if I want to check equality of two sine values how would I go about it?

[image]

Comment: What compiler and operating system does this occur on?

Comment: You should not compare double values for equality. Use `const double epsilon = 1e-10` and check for `if(abs(a-b) < eps)`

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Well, that is true in the general case, but here there's little reason for the computation to be nondeterministic.

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](http://ideone.com/7zVqZz), works fine here (gcc-4.8.1)

Comment: @Agnew: I agree. I was responding to "Also if I want to check equality of two sine values how would I go about it?"

Comment: they compare equal for me (apple clang 6.0)

Comment: using an ancient borland c++ 5.0

Comment: Well there's your problem.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Your comment is totally valid in the big picture, but nevertheless it would be interesting how an apparently deterministic function might fail to return different results for the same argument.

Comment: @Codor Am using Borland C++ , added the picture to make things clear

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan WOW! That works , but i dont seem to get the logic , could you explain ?

Comment: @user123 [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan but it wont help me when i am trying to plot a sine wave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the PC, at least as of old, floating points values were calculated with 80 bits, but were rounded down to 64 bits for main memory. When the compiler recognizes that it can reuse an 80-bit result for an 80-bit comparison you can get baffling results like this. And yes, it's permitted by the Holy Standard.

---

By the way, `void main` is not valid. This means the code has Undefined Behavior and in principle can do anything whatsoever, including doing nothing, or what you expect. In practice it's not that bad, it just makes the code non-portable, but still, don't do it: it's silly to add one character in order to make the code non-portable, so write `int main`.

Answer (score 0):

> Also if I want to check equality of two sine values how would I go about it?

There is a very good example of a floating point "almost_equal" function [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon)

by request, code copied from original source:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, bool>::type
    almost_equal(T x, T y, int ulp)
{
    // the machine epsilon has to be scaled to the magnitude of the values used
    // and multiplied by the desired precision in ULPs (units in the last place)
    return std::abs(x-y) < std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() * std::abs(x+y) * ulp
    // unless the result is subnormal
           || std::abs(x-y) < std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
}
int main()
{
    double d1 = 0.2;
    double d2 = 1 / std::sqrt(5) / std::sqrt(5);

    if(d1 == d2)
            std::cout << "d1 == d2\n";
    else
            std::cout << "d1 != d2\n";

    if(almost_equal(d1, d2, 2))
            std::cout << "d1 almost equals d2\n";
    else
            std::cout << "d1 does not almost equal d2\n";
}
```